# Is it possible to challenge a specific IP address through the CloudFlare API?

Tags: cloudflare

I am trying to create an interface that alerts us of users doing strange stuff on our websites. One feature would be to present a challenge page to specific ip-addresses. But I could not find a way to do that with the api.

I have found a way to blacklist a specific ip-address, but it would be nice to be able to just challenge them through the api.

Answer (score 0):

You could most certainly do so in the UI (may not be available via the API just yet). The Firewall app settings allow you to block, challenge or whitelist.